# How do I exclude a specific row from a result set?

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I want to let the user select a value from a combo box, and then exclude a row from the result set of a stored procedure based on that selection. Something like this:

```
Select RegNo from Vehicle Except select  VehicleID from Trip
```

Comment: I made my best effort at parsing your question and rewriting it so that it makes sense. Does this question still reflect what you want?

Comment: This question is definitely missing important points to get an efficient answer :<

Comment: @dasilvj: Try looking at the first version. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you try to achieve:

```
SELECT RegNo
FROM Vehicle
WHERE _id NOT IN ( 1, 2 )
```

`_id` is the primary key of your table `Vehicle`, put those IDs into the brackets that you want to exclude.

I use the `NOT IN` to allow excluding more than one row if necessary.